# python3/windows-10 UDP socket bug?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10, udp

Not sure what I've got here, but something with python UDP sockets seems strangely busted.  I've isolated a unittest that was failing into it's own simplified code and included it below. It intermittently fails (about 1 time out of 10 runs). I can find no pattern to the failure. Sometimes it will fail the first time, and then succeed the next 9. Another time it will pass the first 5 times, fail once, and then resume succeeding.

The test machine is Windows 10-Pro running python 3.8.1

When it fails, the packet is never sent. I can confirm this running WireShark and tracing UDP packets on the loopback interface. When it fails, the packet is not sent.  I understand UDP is non-guaranteed **delivery**, but  I never considered this could be extended to non-guaranteed transmission. Is it possible I'm witnessing some sort of Windows UDP packet drop scenario?

Note: The code below is a contrived test to demonstrate the issue, but it's the minimal working example (MWE).

```
import socket, threading, unittest

class Testmysock(unittest.TestCase):
    r"""mysock unittest test case"""

    def test_hello(self):
        r"""test hello over udp"""

        def hello():
            r"""reply to server with hello"""
            with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) as sock:
                sock.sendto(b'hello', ('127.0.0.1', 55000))

        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) as sock:
            sock.bind(('127.0.0.1', 55000))
            thr = threading.Thread(target=hello)
            thr.start()
            sock.settimeout(2.0)
            msg = sock.recv(128)
            self.assertEqual(b'hello', msg)
            thr.join(0.0)
```

When it fails, it reports `socket.timeout`, which is due to the call to `settimeout`. I've experimented setting the timeout as high as 30-seconds, but it does not change the failure, nor does it alter the failure frequency.

I have confirmed there is nothing bound on UDP port 55000, and all firewalls are disabled on the test machine.

Any thoughts or ideas (no matter how crazy) would be appreciated.

Comment: UDP is an unreliable transport. There's no reason you shouldn't see failures.

Comment: Hmm. Sending a 5-byte pkt over loopback every 1.5 seconds and we're seeing a 10% drop rate? On sending?!  Something doesn't quite "feel" right about this.